# Cordova Back button Action listener not working

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have an application running Cordova version 10 and I'm trying to override the back button action listener to exit the application and for which I have done the following :

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
                function onBackKeyDown(event) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                }
```

But it is still continuing to perform the default back button action.

Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function onBackKeyDown(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
```

You misspelled event (vs e.preventDefault)